# PySpark RDD: Manipulating Inner Array

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a dataset (for example)

```
sc = SparkContext()
x =  [(1, [2, 3, 4, 5]), (2, [2, 7, 8, 10])]
y = sc.parallelize(x)
print(y.take(1))
```

The print statement returns [(1, [2, 3, 4, 5])]

I now need to multiply everything in the sub-array by 2 across the RDD. Since I have already parallelized, I can't further break down "y.take(1)" to multiply [2, 3, 4, 5] by 2.

How can I essentially isolate the inner array across my worker nodes to then do the multiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.map.html#pyspark.RDD.map) with a lambda function:

```
y = sc.parallelize(x).map(lambda x: (x[0], [2*t for t in x[1]]))
```

Then `y.take(2)` returns:

```
[(1, [4, 6, 8, 10]), (2, [4, 14, 16, 20])]
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick.

I am having an issue now where when I do: sc.parallelize(x).map(lambda x: [(t, 1) for t in x[1]]) 
the output is contained within double brackets [[<answer>]]. How do I remove the outer brackets?

Comment: @AutoOffice I am not sure that is possible because the output needs to be contained inside something – either double brackets to be a list or parantheses to be a tuple

Comment: I found my answer through the .flatmap() function: combining all of the arrays in the tuple into one array within the tuple. the "[[ ]]" was because there were multiple arrays within the tuple.

Comment: That's very inefficient especially in the PySpark because you need to serialize all code

Answer (score 1):

It will be more efficient if you use DataFrame API instead of RDDs - in this case all your processing will happen without serialization to Python that happens when you use RDD APIs.

For example you can use the [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html#pyspark.sql.functions.transform) function to apply transformation to array values:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, [2, 3, 4, 5]), (2, [2, 7, 8, 10])], 
                           schema="id int, arr array<int>")
df2 = df.select("id", F.transform("arr", lambda x: x*2).alias("arr"))
df2.show()
```

will give you desired:

```
+---+---------------+
| id|            arr|
+---+---------------+
|  1|  [4, 6, 8, 10]|
|  2|[4, 14, 16, 20]|
+---+---------------+
```